# (Kotlin Vulkan) vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties shows a total of zero available extensions

Tags: java, kotlin, vulkan

`vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties()` "returns" 0 when called.

I am following the Vulkan tutorial by the Khronos Group: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/

I know that the actual `return` value of the function is the error code. I'm talking about the 3rd `parameter` which in this case is an `IntBuffer` that is being written to. That `IntBuffer` always comes back as 0. Also, everything I have done up to this point has worked including instance creation, validation layers, surface creation and creating the logical device (which actually comes after this part of code but it worked before I implemented this).
Here is the code:

```
private fun checkDeviceExtensionSupport(device: VkPhysicalDevice): Boolean {

    val pExtensionCount = memAllocInt(1)
    vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(device,null.toString(),pExtensionCount,null)

    val availableExtensions = VkExtensionProperties.mallocStack(pExtensionCount.get(0))
    vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(device,null.toString(),pExtensionCount,availableExtensions)

    println("ExtensionCount: ${pExtensionCount.get()}") //this is 0
    println("Available extensions: ${availableExtensions.get(0)}") //which results in an out of bounds here

    memFree(pExtensionCount)
    availableExtensions.free()
    return true
}
```

I have noticed that other people don't even call this method in the first place. Is it necessary? I am fairly sure that you have to specify the device extension in the logical device create info later. Could it just be that my physical device is just not supporting any extensions? Sounds kinda strange to me, though.

And yes, I know that Kotlin may not be the best choice when it comes to programming engines and games and I would be willing to go back to C++ if I get stuck here but for now I am actually quite happy with Kotlin.

Comment: Is `val pExtensionCount = memAllocInt(1) vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(device,null.toString(),pExtensionCount,null)` supposed to be like that? I think you forgot a new line and an indent.

Comment: Also can you run VkPhysicalDeviceProperties on that device?  It may not be the device you think it is.   And can you try just putting `null` in for `null.toString()`?  It may be finding no extension because it thinks you are trying to name a layer.

Comment: Oh those lines were actually supposed to be seperate. I thinkI just formatted that wrong.
null.toString() is necessary because otherwise there would be 2 possible methods that could be called. One wants a ByteBuffer and the other one wants a CharSequence. I will try getting the device properties! Good idea!

Comment: Okay so it turned out that I actually got the wrong device. I don't know which one but the method now returns 78 which is good (I guess?). Thanks a lot! You are doing Gods work here.

Comment: You should probably make a self answer on this, I'd upvote it and it would help others.  Comments are meant to be temporary.

Comment: I'm going to edit your question to account to account for the discussion we had earlier about the misformatted code. In the future know that you can edit your own question at any time with out waiting in the edit queue.  Additionally to format code indent by four spaces all the way around.  There's a button in the editor that will automatically do this to text in the Question/Answer wizard. It looks like the issue came from some one else trying to fix the code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so it turned out that I actually got the wrong device. I don't know which one but the method now returns 78 which is good (I guess?). Iterating through the possible physical devices will help!